# I use the word tokenize function on my dataframe, by writing word_dict, but after executing the error message 'expected string or bytes-like object'

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, tokenize

I want to write the code `word_dict`, by calling the column name `more_clean` on the dataframe, but the error expected string or bytes-like object appears.

This is my dataframe:
[image: dataframe image]

And this is my code:

```
word_dict = {}
for i in range(0,len(df['more_clean'])):
    sentence = df['more_clean'][i]
    word_token = word_tokenize(sentence)
    for j in word_token:
        if j not in word_dict:
            word_dict[j] = 1
        else:
            word_dict[j] += 1
```

and an error message appears like this

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the `sentence` variable is of a `str` type:

```py
word_token = word_tokenize(str(sentence))
```

See the [*`nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize` documentation*](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize):

> `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text, language='english', preserve_line=False)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `text` *(str)* – text to split into words
> - `language` *(str)* – the model name in the Punkt corpus
> - `preserve_line` *(bool)* – A flag to decide whether to sentence tokenize the text or not.